# CakePHP 2.6 : Session Read In Controller Not Working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.6

I have written my `client.id` in session by below syntax.

```
$this->Session->write('Client.id', $client_id);
```

Then I have checked it in view.ctp like below code

```
<pre><?php print_r($this->Session->read('Client.id')); ?> </pre>
```

It's printing array with `id`.

Now in `Controller` I have tried below code to get session `client.id`.

```
$client_id = $this->Session->read('Client.id');
```

In this time I am not getting `$client_id`. Have there any mistake. May anyone help me please ?

Here I adding more code as mention in comment

In user controller I have set user  `$client_id` in login action

```
if($user_role == 'client')
    {
           $user_email = $this->Auth->user('email');
           $this->loadModel('Client');
           $client_id  = $this->Client->find('all',
                                              array(
                                                         'conditions'=>array('Client.email'=>$user_email),
                                                         'fields' => array('Client.id'),
                                                         'limit'  => 1,
                                                         'recursive' => -1, //int
                                          )
         );

         $this->Session->write('Client.id', $client_id);
 }
```

Here Is the code there I have tried to apply this in conditions

```
if($role == 'client'){
           $this->AppComment->recursive = 0;

           $client_id = $this->Session->read('Client.id');


           $this->Paginator->settings = array(
                    'conditions' => array('AppComment.client_id' => $client_id)
           );

           $this->set('appComments', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

I found the error

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'
```

Here is the output for

```
<pre><?php print_r($this->Session->read('Client.id')); ?> </pre>
```

Output I get

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Client] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: everything seems right, I would help if you provide more snippet of your code

Comment: ok let me add more code.I editing my question.

Comment: Everything looks fine.Check data is coming or not in $client_id .

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to do a `find('all')` combined with a limit of 1. It would be much easier to do a `find('first')` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in login action

```
 if($user_role == 'client'){
     $user_email = $this->Auth->user('email');
     $this->loadModel('Client');
     $client_id  = $this->Client->find('first',
                       array(
                            'conditions'=>array('Client.email'=>$user_email),
                            'fields' => array('Client.id'),
                            'recursive' => -1, //int
               )
    );
    if(!empty($client_id)){
       $this->Session->write('Client.id', $client_id["Client"]["id"]);
    }
}
```

And check in your conditions if Session is set or not like this

```
if($this->Session->check("Client.id")){
    $client_id = $this->Session->read("Client.id");
}else{
   //handle if session is not set
}
```

Comment: I am getting same result :( If I use your code then no any value is setting in session, I have checked.

Comment: check now, edited the answer. I there is any record existing with your condition(Client.email => $user_email), It will work

Comment: I get the error exception here.Yes there has a record.

Comment: what is the error and what is output when you apply this code

Comment: Your ans is correct just see my array you have missed 1st param. Please add it I will accept your ans.

Comment: Is it find fast here ?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem just add below code

```
$this->Session->write('Client', $client_id[0]["Client"]['id']);
```

Comment: i added this in my answer, But if write find("first") instead of find("all") then there will be no need of [0]

Comment: Ok please add your ans that you have prefer.

Comment: I m pleased you got your answer